# Bootstrap 4 Full height and width two columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a layout like following using bootstrap 4.

[image]

[image]

Following is my JSFiddle and I think the approach I have taken is incorrect and there's a better way of doing this. And also there are responsive issues.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ef7p3wLm/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid h-100 ">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4 hidden-md-down yellow" id="yellow">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 red">
      Background image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bootstrap grid has 12 column and your total was coming to 14. I have added
`col-sm-4` to `yellow` `div` and `col-sm-8` to `red` `div`.

refer below link for more details. thanks
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid h-100 ">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-md-down yellow" id="yellow">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 red">
      Background image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the write way of following the bootstrap grid layout

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap columns must add up to `12`, yet yours add up to `14` for some viewports.
What you probably want is to have one column at `4` and one at `8`:

```css
.left, .right {
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
}

.right {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 left"></div>
  <div class="col-8 right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The better option is to just use `.col` for the red region so that it occupies the remaining width.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-4 hidden-md-down yellow" id="yellow">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>
    <div class="col red">
      Background image
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```